# How to change type of index expression? ie: c[k]

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexof, keyof

**My Code**

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

import { ILPAsset } from 'shared/types/models';

interface TextMatchFunction {
  (part: string, typed: string): boolean;
}

const textMatch: TextMatchFunction = (part: string, typed: string) => typed.search(part) !== -1;

export const filterAssets = (txt: string, assets: ILPAsset[]): ILPAsset[] => {
  const checkText = (k: string, c: keyof ILPAsset) => (textMatch(txt, c[k].toLowerCase()) ? c : null);
  const curriedCheckText = R.curry(checkText);
  // @ts-ignore
  const bySymbol = R.map(curriedCheckText('symbol'), assets);
  return R.reject(R.isNil, bySymbol);
};
```

**IPAsset's interface**

```
export interface ILPAsset {
  symbol: string;
  lastPayout: number;
  historical: number;
}
```

---

Problem is on this line:

```
const checkText = (k: string, c: keyof ILPAsset) => (textMatch(txt, c[k].toLowerCase()) ? c : null);
```

Typescript expects k to be a number `c[k]`, when it's in fact a key for an object in ILPAsset, which is string that in my case will be `symbol`.

How would this be handled in Typescript?

### UPDATE

A much simpler approach to do this btw, however I got a great answer for future issues in regards to key checking :D

```
export const filterAssets = (typed: string, assets: ILPAsset[]): ILPAsset[] => {
  const checkSymbol = (asset: ILPAsset) => 
    asset.symbol.includes(typed.toUpperCase());
  return R.filter(checkSymbol, assets);
};
```

Comment: If `c` is an  `ILPAsset` why is declared as a `string` ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir you are right, I've reversed the keys, but error is still the same :( `(k: string, c: keyof ILPAsset)`

Comment: How about `(k: keyof ILPAsset, c: ILPAsset)` is what I expect it should be based on how you are using it. `k` is used as a key to `c`. and you say `k` needs to be a key of `ILPAsset` so if `k` is a key of `ILPAsset` and `k` is used as a key to `c`, therefore `c` should be `ILPAsset`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir ah so yeah that removed the error under the `k`, however I'm getting an error on the `.toLowerCase()` now because it still thinks I'm trying to do that on a `number`.

Comment: Well .. that is a different issue... what is the definition of `ILPAsset` ?

Comment: You are right, want to post your answer? And I'll create a new question, btw I added the interface above for ILPAsset.

Comment: I don't think you need another question, I'll answer shortly and we'll take it from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused because you are using `k` as the key to `c`. Since you mention you expect `k` to be a `keyof ILPAsset` that would mean `c` should be `ILPAsset`. So the signature should be:

```
const checkText = (k: keyof ILPAsset, c: ILPAsset) => (textMatch(txt, c[k].toLowerCase()) ? c : null);
```

The left over problem is that now the index access `c[k]` will not be of type `string` since `ILPAsset` contains both `number` and `string` keys.

We have two solutions for this.

We could check if `c[k]` is a `string` and if it not return `null`:

```
const checkText = (k: keyof ILPAsset, c: ILPAsset)  => {
  const v = c[k];

  return typeof v === 'string' ? (textMatch(txt, v.toLowerCase()) ? c : null): null;
}
```

We could also filter the keys so `k` can only be a key taht would be a `string`

```
type StringKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends string ? P: never}[keyof T]
const checkText = (k: StringKeys<ILPAsset>, c: ILPAsset)  => (textMatch(txt, c[k].toLowerCase()) ? c : null);
```

**Note**: The only `string` key of `ILPAsset` is `symbol` so perhaps you should evaluate the need for the `k` parameter at all. Why not just access `c.symbol`?

Comment: Whoa that is sexy! Didn't even know of a type of `never`... and I have to slowly read that type to see what is going on hehe. And you are right, I should just use `c.symbol`.

Comment: @LeonGaban conditional type magic :) https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html